# How to get rid of new icons in yaru-theme-icon in ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes

I upgraded my computer to ubuntu 21.10. But i don't like the new icons in the yaru theme in 21.10.
So i would like to install the yaru-theme-icon from 20.04 by doing something like this:

```
> sudo apt-get install yaru-theme-icon=20.04
```

but apt does not find it, because it can't.

How can I get the Yaru theme icons set as it is in ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new icons that i don't like in **yaru 21.10** are for example saveas and save. And in 20.04 those same icon are from **Humanity** (**yaru** theme inherits from **Humanity** and **hicolor**.). So i just have to remove those new icons.

To summarize what i did:

> cd /usr/share/icons/

> sudo mkdir Yaru20

> sudo cp -r Yaru/* Yaru20

then remove all unwanted icons by hand with nautilus ...

> cd Yaru20/

> sudo vim index.theme

change the name of the theme by Yaru20.
Then Yaru20 appears in gnome-tweaks.